# How to properly sort array in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, file, sorting, rename

How to sort array with String looks like this 'name.extension' and sort only with name order.

My program work wrong then file names are 0.ext, 1.ext, ... and  files are  read  in wrong sequence.

My Program looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;

my $args_count = $#ARGV + 1;
if ($args_count != 1) {
    print "Usage: perl.pl dir_path\n";
    exit;
}

my $dir = $ARGV[0];

chdir $dir
    or die "Error - Please check that $dir exists and is accessible.\n";
opendir (DIR, $dir);

my @fileList = readdir DIR;
sort @fileList;
my $count = 0;

print "Old name: |   New name:\n";
foreach (@fileList) {
    next if -d;
        my ($name,$path,$suffix) = fileparse("$_",qr"\.[^.]*$");
        my ($ext) = $_ =~ /(\.[^.]+)$/;

        rename $name.$ext, $count.$ext;

        print "$name$ext    >>   $count$ext\n";
        $count += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably doesn't matter that the `sort` is taking the extension into account, although by default `sort` uses a lexical sort so that `11.a` will be sorted before `2.a`. If you want a numeric sort then you need to say so and show the format of your file names.

What *is* a problem is that you sort the `@fileList` array and then throw away the sorted list.

If you want the array sorted, you must write

```
@fileList = sort @fileList
```

or if you just want to print them in order, you can sort in the loop, like this

```
foreach (sort @fileList) { ... }
```

By the way, please don't use capital letters in local identifier names. They are reserved for global identifiers like `Package::Names`. Your array would be much better named `@file_list`